# Display a GWT Image in a centered PopupPanel onLoad

Tags: java, gwt, onload-event

Using GWT I am displaying an image thumbnail with a ClickHandler that then shows the full image (can be several MB) in a centered PopupPanel. In order to have it centered the image must be loaded before the popup is shown, otherwise the top-left corner of the image is placed in the middle of the screen (the image thinks it is 1px large). This is the code I am using to do this:

```
    private void showImagePopup() {
        final PopupPanel popupImage = new PopupPanel();
        popupImage.setAutoHideEnabled(true);
        popupImage.setStyleName("popupImage"); /* Make image fill 90% of screen */

        final Image image = new Image();
        image.addLoadHandler(new LoadHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onLoad(LoadEvent event) {
                popupImage.add(image);
                popupImage.center();
            }
        });
        image.setUrl(attachmentUrl + CFeedPostAttachment.ATTACHMENT_FILE);
        Image.prefetch(attachmentUrl + CFeedPostAttachment.ATTACHMENT_FILE);
    }
```

However, the `LoadEvent` event is never fired, and thus the image is never shown. How can I overcome this? I want to avoid using http://code.google.com/p/gwt-image-loader/ because I do not want to add extra libraries if I can avoid it at all. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `onLoad()` method will only fire once the image has been loaded into the DOM. Here is a quick workaround:

```
...

final Image image = new Image(attachmentUrl + CFeedPostAttachment.ATTACHMENT_FILE);
image.addLoadHandler(new LoadHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onLoad(LoadEvent event) {
        // since the image has been loaded, the dimensions are known
        popupImage.center(); 
        // only now show the image
        popupImage.setVisible(true);
    }
 });

 popupImage.add(image);
 // hide the image until it has been fetched
 popupImage.setVisible(false);
 // this causes the image to be loaded into the DOM
 popupImage.show();

 ...
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is really old but just wanted to let you know this really helped me.  I always have problems getting load listeners to work and this is the only solution that seems to reliably fix the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: @rjcarr - Glad it helped :)  Yeah that was ages ago.  I don't work with GWT anymore xD