# Handling onLoad event for IE using GWT

Tags: internet-explorer, gwt

I have an image which on loading i had to call a JSNI function. I had googled that IE doesn't fires or fires before image is loaded for GWT.

I want to have a quick and simple fix to solve this problem.

My code is as follows,

```
Image newWindowImg = new Image("images/new_window.png") {
            public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
                if (event.getTypeInt() == Event.ONLOAD) {
                    addCustomToolTip();
                } else if (event.getTypeInt() == Event.ONMOUSEOVER
                        || event.getTypeInt() == Event.ONMOUSEMOVE
                        || event.getTypeInt() == Event.ONFOCUS) {
                    Window.alert("Hi");
                    addCustomToolTip();
                }
                super.onBrowserEvent(event);
            }
        };
```

Any idea how to make it work for IE.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT doesn't support onLoad event for Images in IE.

There is a bug tracker for it http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=863

According to bug tracker the fix was available in 1.6

Answer (score 1):

If you have static image files, try using [ClientBundle](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html),
Besides that you can also handle it using [gwt-image-loader](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-image-loader/) third party library or see this answer: [Display a GWT Image in a centered PopupPanel onLoad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258157/display-a-gwt-image-in-a-centered-popuppanel-onload)

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I had already read the post Display a GWT Image in a centered PopupPanel onLoad. My problem is that it doesn't works for IE alone. I can't go for any third party library.
Is there any other way around to solve it. Any help would be appreciated.
Had GWT team fixed that issue for IE onLoad enevent. Am using GWT 1.7 and i can't upgrade to a higher version.